# why we need to explicitly define join table in HABTM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand when rails is smart enough to do most of the stuff by its own than why we need to explicitly define a join table while using `has_and_belongs_to_many` association?

Comment: You are talking about the migrations, right? Is this an actual question or more a comment? You do not have to specify it in ruby-code, yet you have to build it first in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is smart here too. You don't always have to tell the name of the join table to Rails; Rails is intelligent enough to figure it out. You just have to create a migration to generate the table, and all the other tasks will be taken care by Rails.

Let's say, you have following two tables:

1. Author
2. Book

An author authors many books, and a book is authored by many authors. Rails  will *automagically* prediect the join table name: `authors_books` - you just have to write migration to create it.

And then, the task is dead simple.

```
author = Author.first
author.books # all the books authored by the first author

book = Book.first
book.authors # all the authors of the first book

new_book = Book.new
author.books << new_book # add a new book to an author
author.save

new_author = Author.new
books.author << new_author # add a new author to a book
```

Remember, it doesn't have to be always this way. You can change the table name as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just consider reading normal forms from database topics.

If Rails doesn't have a join table for `has_and_belongs_to_many` then there would be multiple entries for same record which is against the normal form. Here is a [guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) just to recall the things.